# Combine PhotoSwipe with Magnific Popup (Ajax Type)

Tags: javascript, html, magnific-popup, photoswipe

I'm trying to combine Dmitry Semenov's PhotoSwipe ([link](http://photoswipe.com/documentation/getting-started.html)) with the `Ajax Type` of his Magnific Popup ([link](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#ajax-type)). More specifically, I have a link on my `index.html` file. When it is clicked, an `Ajax Type` Magnific Popup is shown that displays the contents of `other.html`. Within this Popup (i.e. within the `other.html` file) is a PhotoSwipe gallery of images. When I click the images, the PhotoSwipe gallery shows up as expected and it works fine. However, when I click the close button (the 'x' icon) or press the ESC key, both the PhotoSwipe and the Magnific Popup are closed. How can I change this behavior so that only the PhotoSwipe popup is closed? Is there a way to "disable" the Magnific Popup while the PhotoSwipe popup is displayed so that the Magnific Popup does not respond to any clicks or the pressing of keys until the PhotoSwipe is closed?

I only have a very basic knowledge of JavaScript, so I would really appreciate a "hand-holding" approach to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something similar with combining Magnific and Colorbox.  Magnific has the ability to override some parts of its code without having to change the source, as [documented in the FAQ](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#faq).  In my case, it looked like this:

```
// Prevent "Escape" from closing Magnific popup when Colorbox popup is open
$.magnificPopup.instance.close = function() {
  if ($("#colorbox").is(":visible")) {
    // Don't do anything with Magnific if Colorbox is doing its thing
    return false;
  } else {
    // Do what it would normally do
    $.magnificPopup.proto.close.call(this);
  }
};
```

You would have change your `if` test to something PhotoSwipe-specific. Perhaps replacing that line with `if ($(".pswp--open").length > 0) {` would work.  (That JavaScript counts (via jQuery) the number of elements with the `pswp--open` class on them, which appears, at least from the PhotoSwipe demo, to be a class that's added to the mark-up when it's opened.)

Comment: Thanks, this does indeed work! However, this has led me to discover another issue: Magnific adds its "close" button in the upper right-hand corner of the PhotoSwipe popup, preventing me from being able to click the close button belonging to PhotoSwipe. This leads me to ask: Is there a way to just disable all Magnific functionality as long as PhotoSwipe has been initiated?

Comment: You should be able to adjust the placement of the "x" either via the closeBtnInside option in Magnific (unsure if there's something similar in PhotoSwipe), or by adjusting CSS for `.button.mfp-close`. Another option, if it works in your case, could be to close the Magnific popup when you open PhotoSwipe, then re-open it when the PhotoSwipe close event is called. Somebody did that in this fiddle, except with two instances of Magnific: https://jsfiddle.net/matthieuG/zt4coq8f/1/

Comment: I tried getting rid of the "x" by adding `$('.mfp-close').css('visibility', 'hidden');` to the script that initiates the PhotoSwipe. This removes both the "x" on the PhotoSwipe and the one on the Magnific. I would like to set the `visibility` back to `visible` when PhotoSwipe closes, but I can't get it to work. Why doesn't adding `var el = document.getElementsByClassName('mfp-close');
  el.style.visibility = "visible";` to the `close` function work? Is there a way to do it this way?

Comment: Re: your last issue, it's probably because getElementsByClassName returns multiple elements, so you have to specify which one (and if that same class is being used by both libraries, ugh, I'm not sure which order they'd be in). Try `var el = document.getElementsByClassName('mfp-close')[0];`. That specifies the first one in the doc.